# C Sharp DEvelopment of Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms

I'm developing a Windows Application in C sharp.using a Web Browser control to Login to the Https Site and Download the List of files. I'm able to login in to the Site and I'm able to Navigate to the Page where files are listed to be downloaded. When I try Downloading the file using the file URL and trying to Navigate using Web Browser Control a Pop - Up appears asking whether to Open or Save or cancel. How to handle this Pop up and I'm stuck here.

Any Answers are appreciated.

Thanks,
Vinay.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is download a file, you might be better off using [webRequest.Create("Url")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) instead of the WebBrowser control. There are ways of handling authentication depending on the method the website uses.

Comment: Thanks Timothy Strimple, Can You please elaborate the Processes in Downloading the File using HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebREsponse. Currently I'm getting the Cookie. i.e Session Id in Response.Cookies() Method. How to MOve Further. PLease Provide me Whole Code till the File Gets Download, as I'm New to the c sharp DotNet. I really Apprecieate your HElp. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Examples of how to do this are on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.80).aspx) and dozens of other sources online. Just google for .NET WebRequest download file.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to use the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to download files (unless initiated by the user, who can click the save button). Instead, you can use a [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to download the files from your application.

Since you said you have to log in to the website, I'm going to assume that it uses the popular method of using cookies (as opposed to HTTP Basic Auth). To get the cookies from the `WebBrowser`, you can use the `Cookie` property of the `WebBrowser`'s `Document` property.

Comment: Thanks icktoofay, Ya I tried using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. When I request for URL by passing the Credentials like UserName And Password. I will get the Session Id Back in the Response. After getting that Session Id, How to Move Furthur. I'm New to DotNet, Please Help me further. I appreciate ur Help.